# Open new email with readonly subject

Tags: html

I have below code in my Html page

```
<p>
This is an email link:
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someoneelse@example.com&bcc=andsomeoneelse@example.com&subject=Summer%20Party&body=You%20are%20invited%20to%20a%20big%20summer%20party!" target="_top">Send mail!</a>
</p>
```

when i click on the 'Send mail' it opens up an outlook email with body and subject. Is it possible to make body as read only , meaning the user should not be able to enter/change anything in the body of the email. How can we do this?

thanks,
sankar.

Comment: no way of doing that. you would have to control user outlook and that's a security issue. I suggest a backend script like PHP or similar to do what you want

Comment: One way would be to use a contact form on your website and send the email server side with a subject line that you specify.

Comment: You want to look into sending email from the server side, not on the client. When you use mailto you only get to set the default subject, body, etc. and you have no control over edits or if the email is even sent or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mailto:` protocol simply instructs an OS to open the user's default mail-handling program. Because of this, the way a user's computer reacts to the `mailto:` link is dependent on the mail program that the individual uses.

While some programs may support "read only" subject lines or messages, most will not because by doing so you may force a user to send a message that they don't agree with or fully wish to send (hence a security flaw would be exposed).

In order to acchieve this "readonly" effect, you may wish to send email using a server-side library like PHPMailer which gives you full control over certain fields of the email and the user full control of others.

Comment: Regarding the "May support readonly" bit I think this might be misleading. As far as I know, there are NO email clients that support a readonly option when specifying a mailto link.

Comment: ok..is it possible to have a javascript function which sends an email to specific user with specific subject and body on click of a link?

Comment: @scunliffe I have never in my life heard of one, but to say that there is *NO* client that supports readonly files is impossible unless you have personally downloaded and tested every email client in the world.

Comment: @user928700 You would have to use a backend scripting language such as PHP.

Comment: @VCNinc agreed, but the "may" part in combination with "some programs" seems to imply that this is even an option.  Since I haven't seen this available in any app since I started adding mailto links back in 1995?... I don't think there are any... I haven't seen any documentation or an API that even suggests how one would do it, and I haven't seen an app that supports such a feature... I think it is misleading to imply it is a possibility.

Comment: @scunliffe I believe that it _is_ a possibility, you _could_ program a mail application that with read-only fields

Comment: @VCNinc understood... I could program an email program that makes grilled cheese sandwiches too - but in the "history of the Internet so far" it doesn't exist (grilled cheese or readonly mailto links).  The correct answer here is as you noted... this is a server thing, not a client.

Comment: @scunliffe I completely agree with you, this is not a "debate" (although all in fun) that I do not want to continue so let's just leave it as a "hypothetical possibility" ? :)